# How can I reach and beat wave 15 of the Frost Moon?

Tags: terraria-console

Whether I use traps or kill manually, I can't seem to get to wave 15 of the frost moon. Any advice, useful strategies or arena setups that might help? I have a trap arena, but that only gets me to Wave 7 or 8, and doing it manually gets me to wave 6 or 7.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

a VERY good weapon to use for the frost moon and the pumpkin moon is to use the flairon which is a 20 percent drop chance from dduke fishron who is summoned by truffle worms while fishing in the ocean and you get the truffle worms in the mushroom biome underground and they are hard to catch so you need to sneak up on the to catch them with a bug net which is sold by the merchant for 1 gold coin and the merchant is obtained by having a proper npc room which should be 10 by 6 blocks and a chair, background walls, a table , and lighting like torches and the merchant spawnes when there is an open room and you have 50 silver coins or more in your inventory. omg that took a long time to write

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I figured it out. I need to use traps AND kill manually. I can go down and use my Razorpine/Vampire Knives to kill mobs, while they are also getting killed by my traps.